# Updating data-attr on a button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to update the `data-action` attribute for the `('.follow')` element to `unfollow` in the success response but it's not updating.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.follow').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var action = $(this).data("action");
    var url = '/action/' + action;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(v) {
            if (v.response == "OK") {
                $(this).data('action', 'unfollow');
            }
            if (v.response == "E") {
                alert('there was an error');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

***EDIT***

Adding the fact that the element in question is a button, as the offered solutions below are still not working.

```
<button class="follow" data-id="<?php echo $profile->id; ?>" data-action="follow">FOLLOW</button>
```

**2nd EDIT**

Just want to update this question in case anybody else finds themselves in a similar situation.

As it turns out, the accepted answer from Nir Tzezana was absolutely correct. The reason I couldn't get it to work was due to Firefox being buggy. It's not the first time something like this has happened, but I always forget that this could be an issue.

So, the moral of the story.. If you are using Firefox and you are confident that you have working code - yet it doesn't seem to be working - quit Firefox and reboot it (especially if you've had the browser open for a long time). Chances are your code was working the whole time.

Comment: _but it's not updating_ -- How did you ensure that it isn't working?

Comment: 1) because it isn't updating the element and 2) because when I click the button again it's sending the follow action to the server, and not the unfollow action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this)` refers to the return function.
Use a fat arrow function or this `self` trick.

```
$('.follow').click(function () {
   var id = $(this).data("id");
   var action = $(this).data("action");

   // Define self to be the .follow element
   var self = $(this);

   var url = '/action/' + action;

   $.ajax({

       url: url,
       headers: {
             'TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       },
       data: {
           id: id
       },
       type: "POST",

       success: function(v){

           if (v.response == "OK") {

               self.data('action', 'unfollow');
           }

           if  (v.response == "E") {

               alert('there was an error');
           }
       }
   });

});
```

Comment: Neither of these solutions is working although I can see that they are both correct. Does the fact that the ('.follow') element is a button make a difference?

`<button class="follow" data-id="<?php echo $profile->id; ?>" data-action="follow">FOLLOW</button>`

Comment: Try `self.attr("data-action","unfollow")`;

Comment: Bloody hell. self.data... was working after all. Firefox was just playing up. Not the first time I've wasted a couple of hours because Firefox needed a reboot. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

`this` deosn't refers to current element i.e. `.follow` in the `$.ajax()` success handler. You can use [`$.ajax()` context option](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$('.follow').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        success: function(){
           //this: it will refer to clicked button
        }
    });
});
```

And Default action of `<button>` element is `submit`, if the button is wrapped in a form use `type="button"`

```
<button type="button" class="follow" data-id="<?php echo $profile->id; ?>" data-action="follow">FOLLOW</button>
```

Comment: Never used `context` before. This is great! Although in this case it's not working. Maybe it's because I'm calling a button element? `<button class="follow" data-id="<?php echo $profile->id; ?>" data-action="follow">FOLLOW</button>`

Comment: @spice, Is you button wrap in a form? then use `type="button"`

Comment: @Saptal Tried that and tried changing the button to a regular div. `<div class="btn-follow" data-id="<?php echo $profile->id; ?>" data-action="follow">FOLLOW</div>`. And `$('.btn-follow').click(function () {...` Still not working. Am I going mad?